# Error on Deployment of SQL server 2008 R2 reports to SQL Server 2008, Aggregate functions cannot be nested inside other aggregate functions

Tags: deployment, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions, report

I have used SQL Server 2008 R2 for developing my reports, and when I tried to deploy it on hosting server which is SQL server 2008 it displayed an error while deploying a report,

**Error**

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   'Textbox36.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an aggregate function
>   (or RunningValue or RowNumber functions) in the argument to another
>   aggregate function (or RunningValue).  Aggregate functions cannot be
>   nested inside other aggregate functions.

I think following expression is throwing error while deploying from sql server 2008R2 to sql server 2008

**Expression**

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!RegisteredOn.Value  >Parameters!FromDate.Value and  Fields!RegisteredOn.Value  < Parameters!EndDate.Value , 1,0))
```

Is there any workaround for this in SQL server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing the IIF with CASE. I am not sure that IIF is available in all versions of SQL Server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx
--See C. Using CASE to replace the IIf function that is used in Microsoft Access --

Comment: No, it didn't work, so im trying to seprate the sum and case to two expressions ao that I can store one result in to one column and calculate next result based on the first result